# Why does nth-of-type detection fail only with Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using JavaScript/jQuery to detect if browsers support the `nth-of-type` CSS3 pseudo-class. A 5px `padding-left` is assigned in the CSS (see code below) and the detection succeeds if the JS/jQ can read it via `$(document).ready()`.

Everything works fine for Chrome 26, IE9, Win Safari 5.1, and Opera 12, all of which detect the 5px setting. However, Firefox 20, which does indeed support `nth-of-type`, shows the `padding-left` setting as 0px and thus incorrectly fails the test. Why does `nth-of-type` detection fail only with Firefox?

Example code. (Stripped down from my production code. This is also available at http://jsfiddle.net/jma7777/ZnzBN/1/ if you want to experiment with it. Open the console to see the `padding-left` detection results.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pseudo Class Nth-of-Type Detector</title>
<style>
#checkPsdoClass1 tr.rows:nth-of-type(odd) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Checks for style assigned to :nth-of-type(odd)
  if ($('#checkPsdoClass2').css('padding-left') !== '5px') {
    $('#pseudoClassDemo').html('<p>Your browser does not support the <code>:nth-of-type</code> pseudo-class.');
  }
  console.log($('#checkPsdoClass2').css('padding-left'));  // Modern browsers log 5px except Firefox which logs 0px
  console.log($('#checkPsdoClass1 tr.rows:nth-of-type(odd)').css('padding-left'));  // Modern browsers log 5px except Firefox which logs 0px
  console.log($('tr.rows:nth-of-type(odd)').css('padding-left'));  // Modern browsers log 5px except Firefox which logs 0px
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="checkPsdoClass1"><tr id="checkPsdoClass2" class="rows"><td><p id="checkPdsoElmnt">This table is used to test if the browser supports the nth-of-type pseudo-class.</p></td></tr></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know that this is related to your issue, but keep in mind that jQuery didn't support `nth-of-type` until version `1.9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that Firefox doesn't apply padding to table row elements; see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding) for details:

> [padding] applies to all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column

Try assigning the padding to the first child cell instead:

```
#checkPsdoClass1 tr.rows:nth-of-type(odd) td:first-child {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: A quick test suggests this is precisely the issue.